# Action Bar Subtitle Color Doesn't Change

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the actionbar's subtitle color to white... I've tried several solutions on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me..

This is what I currently have, and it's not working.. I'm not using any compatibility library.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

My app's theme in the manifest is Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: did u solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this following.

```
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/application_background</item>
         <item name="errorMessageBackground">@drawable/popup_inline_error_holo_light</item>
        <item name="errorMessageAboveBackground">@drawable/popup_inline_error_above_holo_light</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item> -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

Add this following method in your activity.In that a layout is inflate for action bar and add set this value for **textview** like following.

```
    private void setActionbar() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home, null);
            actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable( R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));

            TextView custom_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.customActionbar_title);

            custom_title.setTextColor(R.color.black);

            if(!Constants.changeOnlyFlag){
                custom_title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.add_new_header));
            }else{
                custom_title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Estimate_Detail));
            }



    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm not using ActionBarCompat, I replaced it with Holo, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" Should be 
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"

Does that help with the @ infront of it?

Or maybe try using @color/white instead of #ffffff

Comment: Are you sure everything is referenced properly? i.e is it actually called "MyActionBar"?

Comment: Yeah, MyActionBar is the name of that custom style, it can be anything as long as I reference to it in the AppTheme.